# How to find new cmdlets in Powershell v3.0

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet, powershell-3.0

I wanted to find the new cmdlets / functions in Powershell. I used the following approach, but not sure if it is comprehensive / correct. Any ideas to find this in a better / different way?

Run the below once from v2 and once from v3 ( and write to a different file)

```
get-command -Module Microsoft.PowerShell.*  | 
select -expand name | out-file e:\poshv2.txt
```

Then use Compare-Object to see what's added ( or removed)

```
Compare-Object (gc e:\poshv2.txt) (gc e:\poshv3.txt)
```

My observation based on this is that there were 25 new cmdlets added ( and none were removed)

One question that was raised as a comment on my blog was that `Disable-PsRemoting`, which appeared in this list, is not really new. The reason it appeared was that it was not in the modules under `Microsoft.Powershell.*` ( and it was  not a cmdlet), but it is in v3.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only difference which you already noted is that in v2 Disable-PsRemoting was a function and in v3 it's a cmdlet. I wrote about cmdlet and parameter changes in v3 (using a similar compare method) on the PowerShell Magazine website.

http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2011/09/15/how-to-find-out-whats-new-in-powershell-vnext/